# Why does this command work?

Tags: command-line

someone showed me this command to get expiration dates of certs:

```
echo | openssl s_client -connect <server>:7002 2>/dev/null| openssl x509 -noout -dates
```

output:

```
notBefore=Sep  8 08:00:30 2015 GMT
notAfter=Sep  7 08:00:30 2016 GMT
```

so it works but I asked why do you need the echo | in front of it cause it seems like you are just echo'ing nothing.  He said cause if you don't put echo | in front of the command then it gives you the output but you don't get the prompt back, it just hangs and indeed this is true but I would like to understand WHY..

Answer (score 3):

Because in linux, `echo<ENTER>` will echo a new line.

in windows it'd be `echo.`  (echo/ works too, and some other things work)

that will be like hitting enter when you get a prompt.

various things could exit a prompt.. echo some character(s), and then when there's no more input, then the prompt exits.  By piping input to it, it takes that input instead of requesting input from the keyboard and waiting for e.g. a ctrl-z in windows. (ctrl-d  at the beginning of a line in linux will do it too, i've just tested it and it's mentioned here https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/16333/how-to-signal-the-end-of-stdin-input )

Generally, when getting a prompt, sometimes echoing any character can work, for example, if you do `dir /p` and you get a prompt "Press any key to continue". Then try `echo a| dir /p` and it will show the listing and hit the key for you.

But do see though with such a command, if it only works for ENTER, or if it works for other keys, and another thing one can look for is if it is looking for an end of input. For example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33814493/why-cant-this-c-sharp-program-be-piped-to-like-the-more-command-and-what-c

So in windows if you type more  then you get a prompt. if you type some characters it sees it as inputted, and it outputs it, as that's what more does, but it doesn't exit. If however you echo even a single character to more, e.g. `echo a|more` then it exits, and that is because that is a prompt that will exit / stop trying to read stdin, when there are no more characters to be entered.

Also if you want to see what has been echoed then you can use xxd e.g. in windows, echo a |xxd -p    and you'll see it has sent an 'a' and a space. You'd see that also if you dod echo a >a.a  then dir a.a see it's two bytes. You can get xxd from cygwin or vim7, and of course for linux.